# Delayed conference review notifications

Tags: peer-review, conference

We recently submitted a paper to a large IEEE conference (ISIT 2019). We have not yet heard back from our reviewers and the dates for the same have passed (it has been a week since). Is this anomalous (delays), or are there situations as per protocol when authors are not notified of their reviews? Is this common to expect in EECS conferences?

**Edit:**
We received an email on the 10th of March that reviews would be provided to authors within the next day; several of our peers have corroborated that they have received the same and responded with rebuttals. The conference website, however does not state this date officially. And for context, the notifications for the conference are due on the 31st of March. The conference website is accessible [here](https://2019.ieee-isit.org/default.asp).

Comment: What dates have passed? The notification date? Review due date?

Comment: @Thomas The review due date. The final notification is due 10 days from now.

Comment: Have a look at : https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/58985/72855

Comment: In my experience the reviews are due to the PC, not the authors, authors only see the reviews around the notification date (or during the rebuttal phase if the conference has this).

Comment: I am confused why there is a "review due date", beyond the internal one for the reviewers, which is normally not disclosed to the public. Can you maybe share the link for the conference website?

Comment: @lighthousekeeper The conference in question is the IEEE ISIT 2019. We received an email on the 10th of March that the reviews would be provided to authors within the next day; several of our peers have corroborated that they have received the same and responded with rebuttals. The website, however does not state this date officially, so I guess there cannot be an expectation that everyone will receive their reviews on time if at all they do. But I was curious whether this selectivity in providing reviews is common..?

Comment: Please incorporate the information in your comments into the question.

Answer (score 1):

From what you have written, it sounds like this is one of the many computer science conferences that is in the process of shifting to include an opportunity for author rebuttal.

Conferences already often struggle to hit their intended deadlines for response, due to the challenges of wrangling reviewers---most do send responses either on their deadline or within a couple of days, but that often involves frantic activity behind the scenes on the part of the program chairs.

Rebuttal rounds are amplifying this problem, as they are still new for many conferences and haven't yet been properly figured into their planning and scheduling heuristics.

Most likely, then, this is a case of conference organizers struggling with a new process and you happening to be the ones being affected by slow reviewers.

Finally, it is worth noting that they didn't miss the deadline that was promised on the website (March 31st), but only the unannounced "bonus" rebuttal deadline.

Bottom line: the particular situation you are describing is not normal, but also not an unusual failure mode, and an appropriate response is to ping the organizers after the deadline has passed by a few days.